# How to get the values from Nested JSONArrays using ORG.JSON Library in java?

Tags: java, json, org.json

This is my sample json , I have an requirement to get the values of datas key from nested json array , I have tried but ran into exception ,
Any help is appreciated .

```
  {
      "configurations": [
        {
          "data": "values",
          "array": [
            {
              "fieldType": "count",
              "datas": "countdata"
            },
            {
              "fieldType": "welcome",
              "datas": "welcomeData"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

This is the sample code I was trying but here I am getting exception as given below ,limitation here is we have to use only org.json library .

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class TestData {
    public static void matchingColumnCount(String input_file_path) throws Exception {
        String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(input_file_path)));
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(contents);
        JSONArray columnDefsDatasValue = jsonObject.getJSONArray("configurations");
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < columnDefsDatasValue.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = columnDefsDatasValue.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("array");
            for (int j = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject temp = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                String string = temp.getString("datas");
                arrayList.add(string);
            }
            System.out.println("get Datas Values" + arrayList);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String inputFileName = "test.json";
        String input_file_path = "/home/Videos" + "/" + inputFileName;
        matchingColumnCount(input_file_path);
    }
}
```

Exception:-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[2] not found.
    at org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:194)
    at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:292)
    at com.planlytx.TestData.matchingColumnCount(TestData.java:20)
    at com.planlytx.TestData.main(TestData.java:31)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < columnDefsDatasValue.length(); i++) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = columnDefsDatasValue.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("array");
        for (int j = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject temp = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
            String string = temp.getString("datas");
            arrayList.add(string);
        }
        System.out.println("get Datas Values" + arrayList);
    }
```

a simple mistake gives this error.Replace i with j in inner for loop in your condition

```
for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++)
```

when i=0 in inner loop; 0<jsonArray.length() so its trying to get jsonobject in of index 1 which is not available.

Answer (score 0):

you have used the wrong looped variable here.

```
 for (int j = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
```

change it to

```
 for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
```